# How is time window defines in TWCS

Tags: cassandra

Can you help me to understand, how **time windows** is defined in **TWCS**

Eg

I'm updating **compaction_window_size** property to **1 day**

When will the start and end points be?

At 00:00 every day or at the time I've set on **compaction_window_size**?

Have you ever been in a situation where your scheduled time windows to avoid multiple major compactions run at the same time?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a great question and it's not obvious - I can't find it explicitly documented anywhere. Looking at the code - when it is choosing the files for compaction on the current window as STCS, it runs through the files and converts the max timestamp of the sstable and rounds it to the time window. The function is [here](https://github.com/apache/cassandra/blob/4bcadc6bfb96e2d1693f74d5135c8408211beede/src/java/org/apache/cassandra/db/compaction/TimeWindowCompactionStrategy.java#L264).

That in effect buckets up the SSTables which will be handled as STCS - the decision on which bucket is STCS vs TWCS is later in the [code](https://github.com/apache/cassandra/blob/4bcadc6bfb96e2d1693f74d5135c8408211beede/src/java/org/apache/cassandra/db/compaction/TimeWindowCompactionStrategy.java#L321).

Intrinsically that appears to align the change over from STCS for the current window, to TWCS for historic windows on the time resolution boundary - the exact logic of that is:

```
long tStamp = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.convert(f.getMaxTimestamp(), timestampResolution);
```

So it's going to in essence make a coarser granularity time conversion, and for the 1 day window, I would expect it to consider any file from midnight onwards as within the current window which will operate as STCS since a coarser conversion will truncate.

For more esoteric windows, the maths is a simple division, which results in a base of epoch (e.g. if the time window was 3 days, which 3? it would be based from epoch in terms of the mathematics of which bucket a file was in)